Time Machine telling me I don't have enough disk space to restore a 64GB file despite having 78 GB free
I'm trying to restore a Docker.raw file which reports 64GB to the os but actually only takes 5 GB on disk.
When I try to restore the file from time machine, it't telling me I don't have sufficient disk space to restore the file and that I need to free up another 54 GB of disk space despite already having 78 GB free.
Any ideas on what I can do to get this file restored?

Not an exact fix to the issue, but a workaround might be restoring it to an external drive if you have one with sufficient free space. You can right-click the item in Time Machine and click "Restore to..."

The estimates from Time Machine (both backing up and restoring) can be conservative (or just wrong). I would restore it to an external drive with enough free space or use Finder or the command line to attempt a copy. This way you don’t have to move other files and reclaim free space until the restore will run.
Use care which tool you choose, since sparse files can get expanded if the tool doesn’t keep the image sparse when it copies and now it will take up a lot of extra space needlessly.
